# How to create company account when saving the form details?

Tags: magento2, forms, create-account, company

I have created customer attributes and created a custom form with the customer attribute fields. Now I want to create a company account when customer fill the form details and save it.

But I don't know where to start. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not this concept in Magento out of the box, you are free to design it by yourself.

Data description:

- I would create a new entity called Company (in the same way as cms block is for instance, cms block is likely the simplest example of entity in Magento)
- then your entity would need to be linked to customer entity somewhat

Ui:

- you would maybe want an admin screen in the backend to Create/Remove/Update/Delete your records
- finally, the frontend would feed this entity likely on customer events (customer_save_after for instance)
- the frontend would need some sort of UX thinking on how you validate the company data, you could even imagine to connect some sort of API (linkedin..)